# Set conditional Validation on Chained Methods in Nette Forms

Tags: php, forms, nette

I am trying to render a form using [Nette\Forms](https://doc.nette.org/en/2.3/forms) where the field types are stored in the database. So depending upon whether the field is an email or a simple text input; the validation type will differ as follows:

```
// For textbox       
$form->addText($field['name'], $field['label'])
     ->setRequired('Enter your ' . $field['label']);

// For Email
$form->addText($field['name'], $field['label'])
      ->setRequired('Enter your email')
      ->addRule(FORM::EMAIL, 'Enter a valid email');
```

If it was just one field I could do it with a a if condition but there will be a lot more fields and it just seems impractical to do this. And since it's a chained method I can't break the methods by putting intermediate if statement like following:

```
$form->addText($field['name'], $field['label'])
      ->setRequired('Enter your email');
    if ($field['type'] == ['email']) {
        $form->addRule(FORM::EMAIL, 'Enter a valid email');
    }
```

Is there a better way to achieve this than using conditional statements for each set of rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `addRule()` on the `$form` object itself, and not the returned value of the `$form->addText()` call.

```
$name = $form->addText($field['name'], $field['label'])
if ($field['type'] == ['email']) {
    $name->setRequired('Enter your email')
    ->addRule(FORM::EMAIL, 'Enter a valid email');
}
```